# Auto inline block to block menu bar

Tags: html, css

I am very new to HTML/CSS and am having trouble structuring and coloring my nav bar. I have two problems.

I have my menu items in a `<ul>` list and they are displayed inline, but I need them to automatically structure themselves in a block if the screen width is changed.

I need to change the background color of "Adoptly" to red. I've only been able to color the word or manually style it, which doesn't work when the margins change.

This is what my code currently looks like: https://gist.github.com/3a5b436746b684306be2

This what the page is meant to look like (focus only on the menu/nav bar): https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/adoptly/index.html

Comment: Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

In the example you gave, the header elements are given a display value of "inline-block" at all screen resolutions. However, at larger resolutions they have a width of "auto". At smaller resolutions, they are given a width of "100%".

Check these lines of CSS in the source:

```
/** Normal/Larger Widths **/
.header li {color: #fff; display: inline-block; font-size: 20px; text-align: center; padding: 20px 30px; margin: 0; }

/** Mobile Widths **/
@media (max-width: 500px) { ul li { width: 100%; } }
```

The @media tag is crucial for responsive CSS, so I suggest doing research into how that is used.